# неточный поиск по списку python

Tags: python, list, search

У меня есть список, в котором мне нужно найти **E** и узнать в каком индексе он находится, но дело в том, что в **4 индексе**('D, E') содержится сразу 2 буквы разделенные запятыми
Написал небольшой код, который спокойно находит все остальные буквы **(включая D)**, но не **E**

```
a=['A', 'B', 'C','D, E','F']
search_what='Е'
number_find=0
for b in a:
     number_find+=1
     grupppa=b.find(search_what)
     if grupppa == 0:
         print(number_find)
```

уже все перепробовал, не получается. В Python новичок, поэтому не злитесь))

Comment: google: "python поиск подстроки в строке"

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант:

```
a=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D, E', 'F']
search_what='E'
number_find=next((i for i,s in enumerate(a) if search_what in s), None)
print(number_find)
```

И ещё... Внимательно проверяйте что вы ищите. А то в вашем коде в списке английская `E`, а в `search_what` вы присваиваете русскую. Так вы никогда её не найдёте.